# How to refresh DataTables from within ajax/error callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm extending the DataTables defaults like so:

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    lengthChange: false,
    deferRender: true,
    displayLength: 25,
    stateSave: false,
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        error: function($xhr) {
            if($xhr.status === 401) {
                wxu.openLoginBox(function(data) {
                    // HELP: how can I get the DataTables object from this context?
                });
            } else {
                wxu.notify({'text': "Could not load list", 'cssClass': 'error', timeout: 0});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Sometimes a user will get logged out and then when they try changing pages or sorting, it just says "Processing" forever. I can catch this by looking for a `401` error response (this is what my app sends when you've been timed out), but then I don't know how to "refresh" dataTables to make the "Processing" message go away so that you can resume using the app.

Please note that I'm extending the defaults here in a `.js` file -- I don't know what element DataTables is going to be bound to at this point.

How can I "fix" dataTables from inside the ajax/error callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **NOTES**

You should not override `ajax.error` since this property is used internally by DataTables, the same applies to `ajax.success`.

> **SOLUTION**

You can add event handler for [`xhr`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event to handle Ajax errors (`json === null`).

```js
// Prevent alert message from being displayed
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';

// Use delegated event handler
// to handle Ajax request completion event
$(document.body).on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr){
   // If there is an Ajax error and status code is 401
   if(json === null && xhr.status === 401){         
      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

      console.log('Session expired');
/*     
      wxu.openLoginBox(function(data){
          api.ajax.reload();
      });
*/

   } else {
      console.log('Could not load list');   
/*       
       wxu.notify({'text': "Could not load list", 'cssClass': 'error', timeout: 0});
*/       
   }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/autezoce/1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax), `ajax` can be a function. It is called with the table [settings object](https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Settings), which can be used to construct a new API object for the table. Then, you can just use the API method to get the processing element (using `.dataTables_processing`) or take whatever other action you like using the other available [API methods](https://datatables.net/reference/api/). Concretely, something like this should work:

```
{
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      success: function (json) {
        callback(json);
      },
      error: function ($xhr) {
        if ($xhr.status === 401) {
          var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
          var container = api.table().container();
          $(container).find('.dataTables_processing').hide();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I don't see it documented specifically, but `this` is also set to the DataTable object in the `ajax` function when it is called. Using that could be a more direct route to your goal, but I think the above aligns more with the intended use.

Comment: I think this might be problematic. I still need to set the ajax URL on a per-instance basis. If I default `ajax` to a function then I lose access to the inner properties.

Comment: If you pass `ajax.url` in with your initialization options like normal, it should be set as a property on your function, and retrievable via the api using [`init()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/init()).

Comment: I thought that'd work, but I've just tried it -- since I'm extending the defaults, when I initialize dataTables with `{data: { url: 'xxx' }}` it's overwriting the whole function. It never gets called.

Comment: You could use an `error` event listener as @Gyrocode.com suggests, then access the processing element in the way I mention in my answer?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the only way to do it, short of an extension. Which I might investigate later, because I don't love binding an event handler to document.body.